# Draw a grid onto an MKMapView

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, mapkit

I'd like to draw a grid into my map, that represents the size of a tile at a certain zoom level. So for example I'd like to have a grid on my mapview that shows the outline of a zoom level 10 tile. So the outline of where this tile would be. No matter if the mapview itself is at zoom level 5 or 15, it should display the outline of where that tile would be placed.

The problem I have is how to calculate the proper rect that represents each visible "tile".

Any help is sooo much appreciated!!!

Or maybe the answer to following question would help:

How can I convert a MKMapRect to a MKTileOverlayPath?

Answer (score 1):

I find that MapKit is way too limited when you want to start doing more and more with maps.

I would reccomend using Google Maps SDK for iOS: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

and then using GMSTileLayer for the tiles:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_tile_layer

In the long run, replacing MapKit with Google maps gives you far more features and options and has better geolocation and reverse geolocation than Apple

Comment: While this might be true, OP should know that Google Maps is a paid service and has a restricted amount of API calls that users can do, where Apple Maps is free and only restricts API access after an unreasonable amount of API calls.

Comment: That answer was from 2014 (5 years ago) and while still relevant, the Apple Maps framework and its supporting location data is much stronger

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at [Mapbox](http://mapbox.com). Between using [TileMill](http://tilemill.com) to create a grid layer by setting the `Map` background to a pattern image, you could then only export zoom level 10 and either host it on Mapbox or export it to MBTiles format (SQLite-based). Then one of the Mapbox mobile toolkits could serve the tiles out as an overlay on your map.